# Alternate history fanfix connecting The Probability Broach and the Draka

Tags: fan-fiction, alternate-history, s-m-stirling

A couple of decades ago, I read online a fanfict that explained the unlikely aspects of the Draka timeline by postulating that a fan of L. Neil Smith's North American Confederacy books had gone back in time to try to recreate them - and accidentally created the Draka timeline. Does anyone remember this story - and is it still online somewhere. As I recall it was told in first-person regretful, from the point of view of the unhappy Draka-creating libertarian.